# Rails pages are linking in non-existent css file when using Stylus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylus

I am trying to use Stylus with a Rails 4 project, but the asset pipeline seems to be naming the compiled CSS wrong and/or linking to the wrong file. If I generate some assets (`rails g assets static_pages`) the served pages all end up trying to link to a file that doesn't exist:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I'm using the `stylus` gem and I've removed the default one for SASS from my Gemfile. I've also tried `stylus_rails`, but that seems to be deprecated and it didn't change anything anyways. Has anyone else encountered this issue when using stylus with rails?

I'm really at a loss here; any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Great styling for your first post here :)